# Get rid of line avobe UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which does not take the whole space on the screen. There are no separator lines between the list items. However there is a light grey line above the whole table which I can't get rid of.

In the image below the line is visible, and underneath there are 2 list items containing only the text "testing". Please advice how to get rid of the line above the table. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It turned out it is not just a line but a frame around the whole table view. I haven't found the answer to the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the line `tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` for me?